# How to make a card from Apple Wallet show up based on location?

Tags: apple-watch, geolocation, wallet

I have my YMCA card in my Apple Wallet. My watch only suggests my YMCA card at certain locations. The YMCA I go to the most does not trigger an automatic suggestion of my membership card. Is there any way to force this suggestion to happen? My devices are a Series 3 Apple Watch and an iPhone X both on the most recent, public iOS and watchOS releases. I have Allow Notifications and Suggest on Lock Screen selected in the settings tab in Apple Wallet.

Comment: To my understanding, the developer of the app that provides your YMCA pass would have to update the pass' location information. [Wallet Developer Guide: Pass Design and Creation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW1)

Comment: The app covers the entire region where I live. I find it weird they would provide some locations with that feature but not others. I wonder if it is possible to stop the suggestions on a case by case basis. Maybe at some point in the past I may have turned off the automatic suggestion, but forgot I did that.

Comment: Have you contacted the app developer about this?